# How to use apply to subtract tuple's elements in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have the following dataset

```
data = {'A': [[(1,5), (7,10), (20,22)],[(50, 52), (100, 110)], [], [(15,17)]]}
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(dt)

                             A
0  [(1, 5), (7, 10), (20, 22)]
1       [(50, 52), (100, 110)]
2                           []
3                   [(15, 17)]
```

and I want to get a new column which is a list that each element in that list is difference of elements of tuples. For instance for row1 there are three tuples as `(1,5), (7,10), (20,22)` and I want to get a list that shows `[4,3,2]` these elements are coming from 5-1= 4, 10-7=3, and 22-20=2 .

The desired outcome could be such as:

```
                             A          B
0  [(1, 5), (7, 10), (20, 22)]  [4, 3, 2]
1       [(50, 52), (100, 110)]    [2, 10]
2                           []         []
3                   [(15, 17)]        [2]
```

I can use `loop` but it is not an efficient way so I tried a better solution as following:

```
dt['A'].apply([(lambda x: i[1]- i[0])(x) for i in x.tolist()])
```

Note: that `x.tolist()` is my attempt to make `x` iterateble.
My solution doesn't work, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt['B'] = dt['A'].apply(lambda x: [b-a for a, b in x])
print(dt)
```

Prints:

```
                             A          B
0  [(1, 5), (7, 10), (20, 22)]  [4, 3, 2]
1       [(50, 52), (100, 110)]    [2, 10]
2                           []         []
3                   [(15, 17)]        [2]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and it is working but I have a question to get a better understanding of coding. 

You are taking each `x` as tuple so you can get `a` and `b` from each tuple, but I thought  each `x` should be the whole `list` 
`example: [(1, 5), (7, 10), (20, 22)]`
in that cell. Why `x` is a tuple and not the whole `list`?

Comment: @JoetheSecond each `x` is one _cell_ from column `A`. So first `x` is `[(1, 5), (7, 10), (20, 22)]`, second `x` is `[(50, 52), (100, 110)]` and so on. So when you put this `x` to for loop `for a, b in x`, then you will iterate over every element `[(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ...]` of this list.